# Altering rows and columns of the dataframe

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I want to change the order of `rows` and `columns` in the `data.frame`. I used `transpose`, but it did not worked as expected. I am new to `apply`/`ddply` in `plyr` package.

Here is the input.

```
Destination S1  S2  S3  S4
Section_A   NA  NA  NA  NA
County1     94  82  121 148
County2     95  87  127 159
County3     96  98  139 182
County4     102 95  142 182
Section_B   NA  NA  NA  NA
County5     120 122 187 254
County6     119 121 185 251
County7     119 121 185 251
County8     114 116 175 236
County9     109 111 165 221
County10    110 112 167 224
Section_C   NA  NA  NA  NA
County11    47  41  33  19
County12    43  36  24  5
County13    143 191 279 415
County14    144 126 215 286
County15    142 135 222 302
```

I am expecting something like this:

```
            Destination S1  S2  S3  S4
Section_A   County1     94  82  121 148
Section_A   County2     95  87  127 159
Section_A   County3     96  98  139 182
Section_A   County4     102 95  142 182
Section_B   County5     120 122 187 254
Section_B   County6     119 121 185 251
Section_B   County7     119 121 185 251
Section_B   County8     114 116 175 236
Section_B   County9     109 111 165 221
Section_B   County10    110 112 167 224
Section_C   County11    47  41  33  19
Section_C   County12    43  36  24  5
Section_C   County13    143 191 279 415
Section_C   County14    144 126 215 286
Section_C   County15    142 135 222 302
```

Can someone please look into this and help me out here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can try something like this:

```
out <- lapply(split(mydf, cumsum(apply(is.na(mydf[2:5]), 1, all))), 
              function(x) {
                x$Section <- x[1, 1]
                x[-1, c("Section", "Destination", paste0("S", 1:4))]
              })
do.call(rbind, out)
#        Section Destination  S1  S2  S3  S4
# 1.2  Section_A     County1  94  82 121 148
# 1.3  Section_A     County2  95  87 127 159
# 1.4  Section_A     County3  96  98 139 182
# 1.5  Section_A     County4 102  95 142 182
# 2.7  Section_B     County5 120 122 187 254
# 2.8  Section_B     County6 119 121 185 251
# 2.9  Section_B     County7 119 121 185 251
# 2.10 Section_B     County8 114 116 175 236
# 2.11 Section_B     County9 109 111 165 221
# 2.12 Section_B    County10 110 112 167 224
# 3.14 Section_C    County11  47  41  33  19
# 3.15 Section_C    County12  43  36  24   5
# 3.16 Section_C    County13 143 191 279 415
# 3.17 Section_C    County14 144 126 215 286
# 3.18 Section_C    County15 142 135 222 302
```

The basic idea is to find where the new "sections" come in (which I presume is where there is a row of `NA` values for columns "S1" through "S4") and use that to modify the original data.

---

Here's a commented version of the code above:

```
out <- lapply(
  ## First, we split the data...
  split( 
    mydf,
    ## ... by a grouping variable we create.
    ## I've made use of the NA rows to create
    ##   the groups.
    cumsum(apply(is.na(mydf[2:5]), 1, all))), 
  ## Next, we apply our function, which...
  function(x) {
    ## ... creates a column called "Section"
    ##   which contains the value from the
    ##   first column of the first row of
    ##   each split
    x$Section <- x[1, 1]
    ## ... and then deletes the first row entirely.
    ## The `c("Section", ...)` part just specifies
    ##    the column order we want to use in the end.
    x[-1, c("Section", "Destination", paste0("S", 1:4))]
})

## The above results in a `list`.
## Put it back into a `data.frame` with:
do.call(rbind, out)
```

---

And here's an alternative approach using `na.locf` from the "zoo" package:

```
library(zoo) ## For na.locf
mydf$Section <- as.character(mydf$Destination)
mydf$Section[grep("Sect", mydf$Section, invert=TRUE)] <- NA
mydf$Section <- na.locf(mydf$Section)
mydf[complete.cases(mydf), ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would you please mind in explaining, `function(x) {
                x$Section <- x[1, 1]
                x[-1, c("Section", "Destination", paste0("S", 1:4))]
              })`. Will this work if `section` names are like `A,B,C,D`. Thanks in advance for your support

Comment: @user3444971, see the updated version of my answer for a commented version of the answer. The `lapply` version should work as long as each new group is identified by a row of `NA` values in columns S1 to S4.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and explaination. That worked for me well. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Actually this one can be done without any of the `apply` family.  Here we have used the fact that S1 is NA for Section rows (but there could be other equally good criteria to select the Section rows). Using this criterion we define `g` to be a vector with one element per row of `DF` which is TRUE for Section rows and FALSE for all other rows.  Then `DF$Destination[g]` is the unique section names and `DF$Destination[g][cumsum(g)]` is a vector with one element per row of `DF` containing the section names.  Finally we remove the section rows using `[!g,]`.

```
g <- is.na(DF$S1)
cbind(Section = DF$Destination[g][cumsum(g)], DF)[!g, ]
```

giving:

```
     Section Destination  S1  S2  S3  S4
2  Section_A     County1  94  82 121 148
3  Section_A     County2  95  87 127 159
4  Section_A     County3  96  98 139 182
5  Section_A     County4 102  95 142 182
7  Section_B     County5 120 122 187 254
8  Section_B     County6 119 121 185 251
9  Section_B     County7 119 121 185 251
10 Section_B     County8 114 116 175 236
11 Section_B     County9 109 111 165 221
12 Section_B    County10 110 112 167 224
14 Section_C    County11  47  41  33  19
15 Section_C    County12  43  36  24   5
16 Section_C    County13 143 191 279 415
17 Section_C    County14 144 126 215 286
18 Section_C    County15 142 135 222 302
```

**2)** An alternative approach using the same `g` as above is to use `ave` to form the Section vector:

```
cbind(Section = ave(DF$Destination, cumsum(g), FUN = function(x) x[1]), DF)[!g, ]
```

**NOTE:** We used this data frame for testing. Next time please use `dput` to display your input in
reproducible form like  this:

```
DF <- structure(list(Destination = c("Section_A", "County1", "County2", 
"County3", "County4", "Section_B", "County5", "County6", "County7", 
"County8", "County9", "County10", "Section_C", "County11", "County12", 
"County13", "County14", "County15"), S1 = c(NA, 94L, 95L, 96L, 
102L, NA, 120L, 119L, 119L, 114L, 109L, 110L, NA, 47L, 43L, 143L, 
144L, 142L), S2 = c(NA, 82L, 87L, 98L, 95L, NA, 122L, 121L, 121L, 
116L, 111L, 112L, NA, 41L, 36L, 191L, 126L, 135L), S3 = c(NA, 
121L, 127L, 139L, 142L, NA, 187L, 185L, 185L, 175L, 165L, 167L, 
NA, 33L, 24L, 279L, 215L, 222L), S4 = c(NA, 148L, 159L, 182L, 
182L, NA, 254L, 251L, 251L, 236L, 221L, 224L, NA, 19L, 5L, 415L, 
286L, 302L)), .Names = c("Destination", "S1", "S2", "S3", "S4"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

**REVISED:**  Minor improvements, expanded explanation, second approach. Added `dput(DF)` output.

Comment: Thanks a lot @G.Grothendieck. This has helped me in alternate ways.